# Simple Commere Email send issues

Tags: email, notification, simple-commerce

Last week I set up a simple commerce section for a client which included two email templates: one to the buyer and one to the seller. In my testing the buyer notice arrived but when other users tested the purchase the notice never came through.

Here is the text of the email:

> Dear {first_name} {last_name},
>
> Thank you for your purchase.
>
> You can download the video: http://www.sitename.com/store/success.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Client Name

Is there anything that would be preventing the emails from getting through to the buyer?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try going to the Communicate tool in EE and sending an email message to one of the buyer's emails? This will confirm whether or not the issue is within EE or is something with the email that is sent.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Good suggestion. I tried it and so far one of the people has received notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the Expression Engine documentation - basement level:

> While you can still use Simple Commerce generated PayPal links to sell items to users browsing your site as guests, the Instant Payment Notification features, such as transaction recording and **email notifications**, will only work for purchases made by logged-in members of your site.

So the system is not broken, it just has limitations.

Thanks.